# Process long query and output data to file

Tags: cron, database

I have several nodes in my site (7822 at the moment) and I need to generate new data from those node values. I have a custom module with all the functions and calculations.

The problem is that, because is so many nodes and the calculations are long, I need this to run on the background in some way.

I also tried to use views because there are plenty of modules that allow me to export the data to a file (I need that also) but in views I can't access my module functions.

How can I solve this problem? In case the queries are long, what solution should I use?

Thanks.

EDIT: Following the advice from Topsitemakers, I tried the following code to loop trough all my nodes and set some new field values but I'm getting some errors:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
    $items['admin/creategamedata'] = array(
        'title' => 'Game Data',
        'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_creategamedata_batch',
        'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_creategamedata_batch() {
    $batch = array(
        'title' => t('Creating Game Data'),
        'operations' => array(
            array('MYMODULE_creategamedata_testing', array()),
        ),
        'finished' => 'my_finished_callback',
        'file' => 'path_to_file_containing_myfunctions',
    );
    batch_set($batch);
    batch_process('node');
}

function MYMODULE_creategamedata_testing() {
    if (empty($context['sandbox'])) {
        $context['sandbox']['progress'] = 0;
        $context['sandbox']['current_node'] = 0;

        $count = new EntityFieldQuery;
        $context['sandbox']['max'] = $count->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
          ->entityCondition('bundle', 'game_results')
          ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
          ->count()
          ->execute();

    }
    $limit = 505;

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query
        ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'game_results')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
        ->propertyCondition('nid', 'value', $context['sandbox']['current_node'], '>')
        ->propertyOrderBy('nid', 'value', 'ASC')
        ->range(0, $limit);

    $result = $query->execute();

    if (isset($result['node'])) {
        $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
        foreach ($nids as $nid) {
            $node = node_load($nid->nid, NULL, TRUE);
            $context['sandbox']['progress']++;
            $context['sandbox']['current_node'] = $node->nid;
            $ft_result = rand(1,10);
            $node->field_ft_result[$node->language][]['value'] = $ft_result;
            node_save($node);
        }
    }

    if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {
        $context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
    }
}
```

Errors:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /batch?id=1128&op=do StatusText: Service
>   unavailable (with message) ResponseText: EntityMalformedException:
>   Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in
>   entity_extract_ids() (line 7818 of
>   /home/.../public_html/.../includes/common.inc).

What am I missing here?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Batch API](https://www.drupal.org/node/180528). It allows you to queue items for processing, which will then be processed by Drupal one by one.
This is already used by core when you for example want to delete nodes on bulk, update modules, etc.

See also the `batch_example` module in the [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) bundle.

Another example can be seen in my Drupal 7 boilerplate [here](https://github.com/topsitemakers/drupal7-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate.batch.inc).

If this is not what you have asked for, update your question please.

Comment: I think these suggestions solve my problem, yes. Thanks!

Comment: @zephirus if you found the question useful, be sure to mark it as accepted (the checkmark to the left)